# rm Can't remove file /var/lib/os-prober/labels

Tags: linux, grub, file-permissions, manjaro

If I run `sudo os-prober` I get
`rm: cannot remove '/var/lib/os-prober/labels': Bad message`
I get the same message if I run either 'sudo update-grub' or try to manually remove it. Even `ls` gives me a similar message with it being unable to access the file. It almost seems I lack the permissions to even modify the permissions, even with root. (Same message with chmod.)

Things I have tried:

- Manually removing the directory, same exception. Did not work even if os-prober was uninstalled.
- Reinstalling os-prober.
- `sudo update-grub` same error message.
- `sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg` same error message.
- `chmod`, `ls` and all other commands return the same message regardless if I use my account or root. `ls -la` gives the error message and shows that there is something called `labels` there but all fields are just questionmarks.

This results in os-prober not working at all and my secondary OS is not showing in GRUB anymore. Never before had a file that I could not even touch as root, so I have no idea what is going on.

General system information

> Operating System: Manjaro Linux
> KDE Plasma Version: 5.19.5
> KDE Frameworks Version: 5.73.0
> Qt Version: 5.15.0
> Kernel Version: 5.7.19-2-MANJARO
> OS Type: 64-bit
> Processors: 24 × AMD Ryzen 9 3900X 12-Core Processor
> Memory: 31,4 GiB of RAM
> Graphics Processor: AMD Radeon RX 5700
> os-prober version 1.77-1
> grub version 2.04-11.1

I have made some minor changes in `/etc/default/grub` but I don't really see how that would affect this? All I did was change timeout style to menu and added a GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT parameter.

What is far more likely imo is that I updated all packages this morning, and something occurred that broke this. I have no idea how to progress from here, so all help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Try `chattr -i`

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Fixed, used to other forums where editing is discouraged.
@tetech Ran `chattr -i labels` and got translated to English (no idea why I get the error message in Swedish) `chattr: Error message when trying to retrieve status of labels`.

Comment: Useful links: our [tour]; more [about editing](https://superuser.com/help/editing).

Comment: @tetech Here is the error message as printed in English. `chattr: Bad message while trying to stat labels`